# "Jump" between columns

Tags: sectioning, columns

I am trying to create a two-column document where I can create sections such that the title of the section is in column 1 and the text of the section is in column 2. 
[image]
Like in the image but obviously I want to be able to add more sections and still have the title of each section line up with the text of each section.

Do you have any suggestions on how to go about this?

## EDIT:

This is my document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twocolumn]{article}
```

To create the piece of the image I posted I wrote:

```
\section{This is the title of the first section of this document}
\newpage
bla bla bla bla
\newpage
\section{Second section}
\newpage
bla bla bla bla
```

This yields the result I want except every section (obviously) ends up on a separate page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show what you have tried so far? Which document class do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  right=3cm,
  left=10.5cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
 {\normalfont}
 {\makebox[3em][l]{\S\thesection}}
 {0pt}
 {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr7cm-3em}}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {7cm}
  {2\baselineskip}
  {0.5cm}

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
  \widenhead{7.5cm}{0pt}%
  \sethead{}{}{Header}%
  \headrule
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\section{This is the title of the first section of this document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Another section}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Another section}

\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]